You don't have write permission to backup destination
Debian 12, using whatever the built-in backup system is.
I have it set to back up to an external drive that's dedicated to this purpose.
When I hit the button to do a backup, it says I don't have write permission.
I have verified indeed, I can't create a file or folder on that drive without using sudo.
How do I grant myself and the backup process the access it needs to do a backup?
Thanks.
Selected backup drive:

Go button and resulting error:

Edit with requested details:

root owns it
Dolphin says Ower can view & modify, group and others can only View.
Was ExFAT, reformatted to ext4, now that button does nothing but the other backup dialog says "Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: Error opening file “/backup/duplicity-full.20240802T203854Z.vol1.difftar.gz”: Permission denied"







What are permissions & ownership? What format is external drive's partition? If backup, really should be ext4 or other Linux format. Post these: sudo parted -l & lsblk -f

debian has no built-in backup system. This looks like a heavily themed desktop environment? Maybe XFCE? I don't know – but that's what's bringing that backup system.

Yeah, I've been messing with the themes. One window I try is the Backups option in the Personalization section of the Settings window. The other one I try (search "Backup" from the launcher menu) seems to be called Dup.
I have xfce installed but I'm currently on Plasma.
Sorry for noobishly assuming things.
Added requested info to post.

@tsilb no need to apologize! I was just curious what that backup was – so Plasma/KDE's backup mechanism! I didn't even realize KDE had that built-in, so thank you for broadening my horizon!

Well, the original post shows xfce's name in the screenshot, so AFAIK it's very possible it did not intend to be called from Plasma.

Check file permissions and ownership on the mount point for the removable drive.

Took ownership of the drive. If I'm right, it looks like the xfce one is now doing nothing when I click "save new backup", but the other one succeeds. I see files on the backup drive now called Duplicity-full.*.gpg  which I'm assuming looks right; looks better than the nothing I got before.
Want to post that as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Please [edit] your Question, and show what type of filesystem is used on the drive (sudo lsblk -f), and how it's mounted (mount). Do not reply via Add Comment.
